# Rigging issues and animation issues

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

[image]

I created this objected and here is how I rigged it. I have already parented the object with the rigs with automatic weights.

[image]
[image]

Here are the issues I am getting. First of all as you can see if I were to move the foot, for some reason the legs stretch out weirdly. Second of all, how come the leg bones are not moving with the foot bone?

May I know what the issues are and how do I solve these issues please?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the leg stretching is because the foot bone is controlling most of the leg mesh. The leg bones are only slightly affecting the mesh, and thus you get stretching when both bones are 'pulling' on the same mesh. You will need to properly weight paint your mesh (or manually assign them in edit mode) and then work on your skeleton. I would suggest looking up tutorials for setting up IK constraints as that should do what you want.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU Here is a good tutorial that will explain everything way better than I can here. He sets up a rig with IK constraints, and also shows how to properly weight paint your character.

Comment: It also looks like his head bone might be in the wrong position, and the foot bone is not a proper child of the shin bone.